# How can I define this variable so that it doesn't read an error?

Tags: java

Started learning java the other day, I probably just defined the variable incorrectly. In the script below, the variable x is showing a "symbol not found error" during compilation. I've tried changing the variable name, defining it in the head of the code, and checking all of my braces. Can somebody tell me what's wrong?

The Code:

```
public class covidSim {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        int currentDay=0;
        int currentCases=1;
        int targetDay=100;
        while(currentDay < targetDay) {
            int exeNum = currentCases;
            System.out.println("Day|");
            while(exeNum > 0) {
                int randomSpread = (int)(Math.random() * 9);
                if (randomSpread > 0 && randomSpread < 5) {
                    int x = 0;
                }
                if (randomSpread > 4) {
                    int x = (int)(Math.random() * 5);
                }
                exeNum--; 
                currentCases = currentCases + x;
            }
            System.out.println(currentCases);
            System.out.println(currentDay);
            currentDay++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you should stick to a more common indentation and brace positioning style (for example see how I modified your code). It makes it a lot clearer where each block starts and ends.

Comment: On to your problem, you should define `int x` *before* those `if`s, so it's accessible afterwards, and just do `x = 0` and `x = (int)(Math.random() * 5)`.

Comment: `x` is only defined inside those if statements.  Think about this from a pure logic standpoint, it has nothing to do with syntax.  If neither of those if statements evaluate to true, what should the value of `x` be?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to pull the declaration of `x` out of the two `if` statements and put it above them so that it is defined for all the places where it is referenced.  Here's the way that bit of code should look:

```
int x = 0;
int randomSpread = (int)(Math.random() * 9);
if (randomSpread > 0 && randomSpread < 5) {
    x = 0; }
if (randomSpread > 4) {
    x = (int)(Math.random() * 5); }
exeNum--;
currentCases = currentCases + x; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are defining `x` inside of the if statements and then trying to access it outside.  Define `x` above the first if statement.  You can only use a variable that is within the scope that it was defined.

```
while(exeNum > 0) {
   int randomSpread = (int)(Math.random() * 9);
   int x = 0;
   if (randomSpread > 0 && randomSpread < 5) {
       x = 0;
   }
   if (randomSpread > 4) {
       x = (int)(Math.random() * 5);
   }
   exeNum--; 
   currentCases = currentCases + x;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code:

```
int exeNum = currentCases;
while(exeNum > 0) {
  int randomSpread = (int)(Math.random() * 9);
  int x = 0;
  if (randomSpread > 4) {
    x = (int)(Math.random() * 5); 
  }
  exeNum--; 
  currentCases = currentCases + x; 
}
```

You don't need to specify this condition anymore, since x only changes to different value when `randomSpread > 4`:

```
if (randomSpread > 0 && randomSpread < 5) {
    int x = 0; }
```